# An array of alias variables in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, reference

I want to create an array which include variables of another arrays and the variables should be copied as alias (i.e not by values).

For example

```
int* x;
int* y;
int* z[4];   // What should I do if length of z is not known initially.
x =new int[2];
y= new int[2];
x[0]=1;
x[1] =2;
y[0]=3;
y[1]=4;
z[0] =&x[0];
z[1] = &x[1];
z[2] =&y[0];
z[3] =&y[1];
```

Here, array `z` is made by references of `x` and `y`. The changes made in 'z' will be seen in `x` and `y` and vice versa.

WHAT I NEED:
2)  `z` is now array of pointers to integers. How do I convert it into array of integers?

3) Since pointers are difficult to manage, how do I get same functionality with vectors. According to my knowledge, a vector cannot store references.

Comment: Would `std::reference_wrapper` help?

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is with 1). You already allocate `z` at run time. 2) `z` is not an array of pointers to integers.

Comment: and `std::vector` to replace raw pointer.

Comment: @user8153630  You can use the samy syntax z[0] =&x[0];
z[1] = &x[1]; and so on. except that you need to allocate the array like int ** z = new int * [N];

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, Ok thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of the array is that the memory is sequential. This means every element comes after the other.(e.g `arr[0]` is the address of the first element and this is the same as `*arr`. If you need the second element you'll type `arr[1]` which is `(*arr)+1`).
If you want to create an array with elements of two other arrays you must create a third array and copy the values (`z[0] = a[0];`...) 
For dynamic allocation you can use vector which has a constructor who accepts an integer value.  `std::vector<int> z = std::vector<int>(a.size() + b.size())`

This is the only way to do it without storing the pointers.
Note that if you copy something from container a to container b and then you change it in container a it will not change in container b.

Comment: 1) Vectors cannot store refs. You need to wrap them in a `std::reference_wrapper`. 2) A ref is *not* a restricted pointer. It’s an alias name for a specific object and acts differently from a pointer, esp. regarding object copying. Your compiler probably implements refs as pointers *as an implementation detail*; but from the point of view of the C++ language pointers and refs are distinct concepts and it’s a good idea to thinik about them like that. 3) Is your vector example pseudo-code? There are some template parameters missing. 4) Why in the world would you want to `new` a `std::vector`!?

Comment: Should I answer your questions or you are just correcting my answer?

Comment: It was mostly meant as corrections. But if you have a valid use case for `new`ing a vector, I’d be genuinely interested.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code snippet

```
 int *z;
 z = new int[N];     //N is integer.
 z = &x[0];
```

you should write

```
 int **z;
 z = new int * [N];     //N is integer.
 z[0] = &x[0];
```

Or you could use the class template `std::vector<int *>` instead of the array.